# AWS Glue Job Cloudformation - Values Set in Cloudformation Not Sticking

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue

**Cloudformation Setup Below is not behaving as I expected.**
The following variables are not being set with the the template below. When the variables are set manually the job runs successfully.

- IAM Role
- Type
- Language

---

```
Description: "AWS Glue Job Test"
Resources:
  MyJobRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          -
            Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
              Service:
                - "glue.amazonaws.com"
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
      Path: "/"
      Policies:
        -
          PolicyName: "root"
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              -
                Effect: "Allow"
                Action: "*"
                Resource: "*"
  MyJob:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Job
    Properties:
      Name: cf-job1
      Command:
        Name: test-etl1
        ScriptLocation: "s3://project_bucket/releases/latest/mixpanel_job.py"
        PythonVersion: "3"
      Description: "Testing setup config"
      ExecutionProperty:
        MaxConcurrentRuns: 2
      MaxRetries: 2
      GlueVersion: "3.0"
      WorkerType: "G.1X"
      NumberOfWorkers: 2
      Timeout: 2880
      DefaultArguments:
        "--class": "GlueApp"
        "--enable-continuous-cloudwatch-log": "true"
        "--enable-job-insights": "true"
        "--enable-metrics": "true"
        "--enable-spark-ui": "true"
        "--extra-jars": "s3://project_bucket/releases/latest/jars/delta-core_2.12-1.0.1.jar"
        "--extra-py-files": "s3://project_bucket/releases/latest/lib.zip"
        "--job-bookmark-option": "job-bookmark-disable"
        "--job-language": "python"
        "--spark-event-logs-path": "s3://project_bucket/logs/"
      Role: !Ref MyJobRole
```

[Result of Stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDMl3.png)

Comment: Sadly your question is not clear and lacks details. What is the full template? How do you deploy it exactly so that it does not work?

Comment: @Marcin did you look at the screenshot of result of Stack?

Comment: For example --job-language: python & Role: MyJobRole is the suggested parameter via the AWS Glue Cloudformation documents yet it's not resulting in setting the parameters when creating the stack

Comment: @marcin, so as for you deployment question, As stated in the title, this is a Cloudformation template. Cloudformation is an AWS infrastructure as code tool. The idea is here is to not be doing manual release and use automation. The automation will be conducted via circleci. Furthermore, Using AWS CLI with temporary access will conduct an aws cloudformation update-stack template.yml

Comment: This is the full template, if you spend some time on the AWS Glue Cloudformation document you will see the available parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with AWS Cloudformation on the Glue Team.

A default IAM role to run the job can only be SET with a physical ARN string value pointing to another ROLE

--job-language parameter doesn't set correctly which is a known issue. This must be done manually via the Glue Console

Type parameter in the console still doesn't have a cloudformation parameter & must be set manually.

True automation can not be achieved at this time.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this also.

Change from

```
      Role: !Ref MyJobRole
```

to

```
      Role: !GetAtt MyJobRole.Arn
```

and it will work fine. :D

For reference the relevant docs section for the cloudformation resource type is https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html#aws-resource-iam-role-return-values